# Dúvida com herança em método Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método, herança, genéricos

Tenho a interface abaixo

```
public interface BaseRelatorioDTO extends Serializable {

    public BaseFiltroDTO getFiltro();

    public List<? extends BaseRespostasDTO> getRespostas();

}
```

E gostaria de criar o método

```
public void setRespostas(final List<? extends BaseRespostasDTO> respostas);
```

Porém ao criar este método, todas as classes que implementam `BaseRelatorioDTO` e já têm este método começam a dar o erro

> Name clash: The method `setRespostas(List<? extends RespostaHorariosDTO>)` of type `RelatorioHorariosDTO` has the same erasure as `setRespostas(List<? extends BaseRespostasDTO>)` of type `BaseRelatorioDTO` but does not override it.

Segue exemplo de uma das classes:

```
public class RelatorioHorariosDTO implements BaseRelatorioDTO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3828618335258371680L;

    private FiltroHorariosDTO filtro = new FiltroHorariosDTO();
    private List<RespostaHorariosDTO> respostas = new ArrayList<RespostaHorariosDTO>();

    @Override
    public FiltroHorariosDTO getFiltro() {
        return this.filtro;
    }

    @Override
    public List<RespostaHorariosDTO> getRespostas() {
        return this.respostas;
    }

    /**
     * @param respostasParam the respostas to set
     */
    public void setRespostas(final List<RespostaHorariosDTO> respostasParam) {
        this.respostas = respostasParam;
    }
}
```

Se vocês observarem meu método `setRespostas` espera como parâmetro uma lista de `RespostaHorariosDTO`, sendo esta classe escrita conforme abaixo:

```
public class RespostaHorariosDTO implements BaseRespostasDTO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5505724855293262084L;

    // Atributos e métodos acessores
}
```

O que estou fazendo errado que o método não pode ser declarado na interface para que eu obrigue todas as classes que implementem `BaseRelatoriosDTO` implementem o método `setRespostas`?

Comment: poderia mostrar a implementação do `setRespostas(List) of type RelatorioCaixaVisitaEmpresaDTO` ?

Comment: @Math Uma é `RelatorioHorarios` a outra `RespostaHorarios`.

Comment: verdade, desculpa o engano, poderia atender minha primeira solicitação então?

Comment: @Math Eu copiei um dos erros que aconteceu para todas as classes que implementem `BaseRelatorioDTO`. Este mesmo erro acontece para `RelatorioHorariosDTO`, vou mudar o nome da classe ali no erro que relatei, ok?

Comment: @Math Já mudei. Sua solicitação foi atendida como você esperava?

Comment: acredito que sim, é que estou sem tempo agora, vou poder ver isso mais tarde, valeu

Comment: @Math Agradeço sua ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que Java descarta os tipos genéricos após a compilação (o tal de *erasure* que o erro está mencionando), de modo que duas funções com a mesma assinatura variando só os tipos genéricos são interpretadas como a mesma função. Exemplo:

```
interface A {
    public void foo(int x);           // OK
    public void bar(List<Integer> x); // Após compilação vira:
                                      // public void bar(List x)
}

class B implements A {
    public void foo(long x) { ... }       // Não tem problema: é overload, não override

    public void bar(List<Long> x) { ... } // Após compilação vira:
                                          // public void bar(List x)
                                          // Ops, é igual o da interface, então é override
                                          // Mas o tipo genérico é diferente... E agora?
}
```

Infelizmente, creio que você não pode ter esse método da forma como gostaria. Pelo [princípio da substituição de Liskov](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov), se `RelatorioHorariosDTO` implementa `BaseRelatorioDTO` então você deveria poder usar um objeto dessa classe onde quer que uma instância que realiza essa interface seria esperada. Portanto, suponha que:

```
class MeuDTO implements BaseRespostasDTO { ... }
List<MeuDTO> lista = new ArrayList<MeuDTO>();

BaseRelatorioDTO x = new RelatorioHorariosDTO();
x.setRespostas(lista);
```

A última linha é válida: `BaseRelatorioDTO.setRespostas` aceita qualquer `List` cujo tipo genérico seja subtipo de `BaseRespostasDTO`, e `lista` satisfaz esse requisito. Entretanto, a classe `RelatorioHorariosDTO` só aceita listas com `RespostaHorariosDTO`, então passar essa lista seria um erro. O compilador não consegue resolver esse dilema, então proíbe construções desse tipo.

A alternativa é toda implementação de `BaseRelatorioDTO` ter um método simples:

```
public void setRespostas(List<BaseRespostasDTO> respostasParam)
```

e fazer *casts* quando necessário... ([exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/ly7RK0)) Talvez existam outras opções, mas não tenho experiência suficiente com genéricos em Java para indicar uma alternativa satisfatória.

---

**Atualização**: por que o compilador aceita um valor de retorno diferente no `getRespostas`, mas não um parâmetro diferente no `setRespostas`? Porque em Java os tipos de retorno são **covariantes**, mas os parâmetros são **invariantes**:

```
interface C {
    public A foo();
    public void bar(A param);
}

class D implements C {
    public B foo() { ... }            // OK, override em C.foo
    public void bar(B param) { ... }  // O parâmetro é diferente: é overload, não override
                                      // (não importa se é subclasse, ainda assim é overload)
                                      // Faltou void bar(A param) - erro
}
```

Ou seja, se Java desse suporte a tipos de entrada **covariantes** (quase linguagem nenhuma dá - exceto Eiffel) então você poderia escrever suas classes tal como estão. Se Java suportasse tipos de entrada **contravariantes** (muitas linguagens suportam), você poderia usar um tipo mais geral (ex.: `List<Object>`), mas não um mais específico. Mas como em Java a entrada é **invariante**, pra ser considerado *override* é preciso que os parâmetros do método sejam idênticos à da superclasse/interface.

Comment: Mas por que, então, funciona para o `getRespostas()` como você pode ver no código que apresentei?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Ótima pergunta, talvez eu esteja redondamente enganado. A mesma lógica que usei pro `setRespostas` *deveria* valer também pro `getRespostas`. Nesse caso, já tentou marcar as subclasses com `@Override` e ver se o compilador aceita? Vou fazer uns testes adicionais, quando der volto aqui com os resultados.

Comment: Ao colocar esta anotação ele gera outro erro falando que devo fazer override do método na hierarquia e não estou fazendo, por isso não posso usar esta anotação. Se você reparar uso esta anotação nos `get`'s das classes que implementam `BaseRelatorioDTO`.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Custou pra cair a ficha, mas minha resposta original está correta. Veja a edição. Em Java tipos de saída são **covariantes**, mas tipos de entrada sao **invariantes**. Ou seja, aquilo que o compilador aceita no valor de retorno não vai necessariamente aceitar no parâmetro da função. `getRespostas` está ok, `setRespostas` não... :(

Answer (score 2):

Esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10891/6528) esta ótima.

Caso queira uma solução para a implementação:

```
public class RelatorioHorariosDTO implements BaseRelatorioDTO<RespostaHorariosDTO> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3828618335258371680L;

    private FiltroHorariosDTO filtro = new FiltroHorariosDTO();
    private List<RespostaHorariosDTO> respostas = new ArrayList<RespostaHorariosDTO>();

    @Override
    public FiltroHorariosDTO getFiltro() {
        return this.filtro;
    }

    @Override
    public List<RespostaHorariosDTO> getRespostas() {
        return this.respostas;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRespostas(List<RespostaHorariosDTO> respostasParam) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

E para a interface:

```
public interface BaseRelatorioDTO<T extends BaseRespostasDTO> extends Serializable {

    public BaseFiltroDTO getFiltro();
    public List<T> getRespostas();
    public void setRespostas(final List<T> respostasParam);

}
```

---

**Editado**

Adicionado metodo setRespostas genérico.

Comment: E como seria o `setRespostas`?

Comment: Infelizmente deu o mesmo erro que relatei no início da pergunta.

Comment: Aqui não da o erro. Você adicionou corretamente os tipos genericos BaseRelatorioDTO<RespostaHorariosDTO> e interface BaseRelatorioDTO<T extends BaseRespostasDTO>???